# IIS7 ADODB VBScript runtime error '800a01ad' Classic ASP - read lots, cannot resolve

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, adodb

I have installed IIS 7 on my dev machine after a drive crash. Previously running IIS 6. Most sites I have use Classic ASP and use the following code:

```
Set con  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

I'm now getting the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
>   ActiveX component can't create object

I've researched this for weeks and have tried heaps of suggestions that I have read on various posts, nothing works, which is incredibly frustrating...

Running Windows 7 64Bit and I tried:

1. Application Pool is set to "Enable 32-Bit Applications" TRUE (also tried FALSE)
2. ADO is installed
3. Permissions is set to Read/Execute for IUSR [machine] and have also tried the same for "Everyone"

Really would appreciate some help on this otherwise the only option I can see is going back to IIS 6 which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: What you have described should work fine. This is just a wild guess but is there a dll in ADO which needs to be registered?

Comment: Thanks John, had previously tried that but to no avail

Comment: Did you try uninstalling IIS and reinstalling?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Yep tried a ful reinstall also.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I did to run the old 32-bit component (created in VB6) to the 64-bit Windows Server 2012:

1. Register component using the regsvr32 in SysWow64 folder, NOT the default in System32 folder:

i.e. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe pathOfTheComponent

2. Locate the Application Pool you use, the set Enable 32-Bit Applications" to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Ive run in to a simular problem some year ago, where the ASP-script needed some system DLL that it mysteriously didnt have access to.
Just to rule out security permissions, set the App pool to run as `[System]` in IIS.

if you still have problems, then at least you know that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks David, I tried as you suggested assuming you meant localSystem however that made no difference I'm afraid. Tried also a few other parameters but no go.